# EXIF key names explanations

Tags: metadata, exif

Does anyone know of a good explanation of EXIF key names?  I am writing a photo organizer and want to get as much information as possible out of the photo as I can.

However, the EXIF key names are not very helpful.  For example, from what I can tell (by exporting images from iPhoto)

album or set name is stored as 'fixture_identifier'
tags or keywords are stored as either 'keywords' or 'subject'

And so on.

Anyone have some valuable insight in this area?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of EXIF tags:

https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

Thing is that you cannot be sure of what a camera or application will put in each, so you'll have to create code to handle those corner cases (where tags or keywords are in either keywords or subject).

Also, there are maker specific tags, as you can see in the tag id 0x927c, which you should also handle specifically.

Comment: exiftool, which this post references, is excellent and provides the most EXIF info I've seen. The supporting documentation is very good too.

Answer (score 4):

All listed here:

http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html

Answer (score 4):

The exiv2 library has a list of EXIF tags, see http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html